# How to skip JSON fields in Struct on input and display them on output, and accept certain fields in input and skip them in output in Golang?

Tags: json, go, struct, go-gorm

I'm writing a webservice in Go using Echo framework and Gorm.
I have a `User` struct that looks like this:

```
type User struct {
    ID    uint   `json:"user_id"`
    Email string `json:"email_address,omitempty" validate:"required,email"`
}
```

I'm accepting `POST` requests with a `Content-type: application/json`.
I want my input to be `{"email_address": "email@email.com"}` and my output to be `{"user_id": 1}`

How can I forbid users from submitting `ID` in the request (so they can't create records with certain `ID`s), but keep `ID` in the response?
Right now I'm doing `user.ID = 0` right before save, but I wonder if there's a better way to do it?

I also want to skip `Email` in output. Right now I'm doing `user.Email = ""` right before the output. Is there a better way for that also?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

While icza's answer proposes a nice solution, you could also employ JSON marshaling auxiliary methods `MarshalJSON/UnmarshalJSON`:

```
func main() {
    // employing auxiliary json methods MarshalJSON/UnmarshalJSON
    user := User{ID: 123, Email: `abc@xyz.com`}
    js, _ := json.Marshal(&user)
    log.Printf("%s", js)

    input := UserInput(user)
    js, _ = json.Marshal(&input)
    log.Printf("%s", js)

    output := UserOutput(user)
    js, _ = json.Marshal(&output)
    log.Printf("%s", js)
}

type User struct {
    ID    uint   `json:"user_id"`
    Email string `json:"email_address,omitempty" validate:"required,email"`
}

type UserInput User

func (x *UserInput) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        Email string `json:"email_address,omitempty" validate:"required,email"`
    }{
        Email: x.Email,
    })
}

type UserOutput User

func (x *UserOutput) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        ID uint `json:"user_id"`
    }{
        ID: x.ID,
    })
}
```

Which gives us:

```
[  info ] main.go:25: {"user_id":123,"email_address":"abc@xyz.com"}
[  info ] main.go:29: {"email_address":"abc@xyz.com"}
[  info ] main.go:33: {"user_id":123}
```

On [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1uCW9jj_p4).

Answer (score 2):

I extend your example by making it more general, and I show an elegant solution to the more general problem.

Let's assume that in `User` there are:

- some fields that must be parsed only from the input
- some fields that must appear only in the output
- and there are some fields that must be parsed from input *and* must also appear in output

Your example is a "subset" of this (as in your example there are no common fields).

This can be elegantly solved without repeating fields using [embedding](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types). You may create 3 separate types; one for the common fields `UserBoth`, one for the input-only fields `UserIn`, and one for the output-only fields `UserOut`:

```
type UserBoth struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

type UserIn struct {
    *UserBoth
    Email string `json:"email"`
}

type UserOut struct {
    *UserBoth
    ID uint `json:"id"`
}
```

Note that `UserBoth` (or rather `*UserBoth` to avoid duplicating the struct value) is embedded in both `UserIn` and `UserOut`, because we want those fields in both.

Now if you have an input that contains all fields (even though we don't want all):

```
const in = `{"name":"Bob","age":23,"Email":"as@as.com","id":123}`
```

Unmarshaling into a value of `UserIn` will only parse what you want:

```
uin := UserIn{UserBoth: &UserBoth{}}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(in), &uin)
fmt.Printf("%+v %+v %v\n", uin, uin.UserBoth, err)
```

Output (note that the `Email` field is parsed but `ID` isn't):

```
{UserBoth:0x1050e150 Email:as@as.com} &{Name:Bob Age:23} <nil>
```

And when you want to generate output:

```
uout := UserOut{UserBoth: uin.UserBoth}
// Fetch / set ID from db:
uout.ID = 456
out, err := json.Marshal(uout)
fmt.Println(string(out), err)
```

Output (note that the `ID` field is present but `Email` isn't):

```
{"name":"Bob","age":23,"id":456} <nil>
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JTRKmIt3Oe).

#### Having a "unified" `User`

The above example used 2 different structs: `UserIn` for parsing and `UserOut` to generate the output.

If inside your code you want to use a "unified" `User` struct, this is how it can be done:

```
type User struct {
    UserIn
    UserOut
}
```

Using it:

```
uboth := &UserBoth{}
u := User{UserIn{UserBoth: uboth}, UserOut{UserBoth: uboth}}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(in), &u.UserIn)
fmt.Printf("%+v %+v %v\n", u, u.UserIn.UserBoth, err)

// Fetch / set ID from db:
u.ID = 456
out, err := json.Marshal(u.UserOut)
fmt.Println(string(out), err)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DN_-0XPhKv).